# ¿Como llenar data table de vuetify con datos obtenidos mediante firebase, vuejs?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuetify

Buen día, actualmente tengo la siguiente tabla utilizando vuetify:

```
 <v-data-table
                    :headers="complex.headers"
                    :search="search"
                    :items="nuevosComunicados"
                    :rows-per-page-items="[10,25,50,{text:'All','value':-1}]"
                    class="elevation-1"
                    item-key="items"
                    no-data-text="No existen datos"
                    v-model="complex.selected"
                    >
                    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">         
                    <td>{{ props.item.titulo }}</td>
                    <td>{{ props.item.mensaje }}</td>
                    <td>
                    <v-btn depressed outline icon fab dark color="primary" small @click="modaleditarComunicado(props.item)">
                        <v-icon>edit</v-icon>
                    </v-btn>
                    <v-btn depressed outline icon fab dark color="pink" small @click="modaleliminarComunicado(props.item)">
                        <v-icon>delete</v-icon>
                    </v-btn>
                    </td>
                    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

y de esta forma obtengo la data de firebase:

```
    data () {
         return {
           nuevosComunicados:'',
        }
    },
    created(){
          firebase
           .database()
           .ref('comunicados')
           .on('value', snapshot => this.obtenerComunicados(snapshot.val()))
     },
   methods: {
        obtenerComunicados(comunicados){
         console.log("OBTENER COMUNICADOS");
         console.log(comunicados);
             },
 }
```

lo cual me responde de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es decir me devuelve un objeto de objetos con los cuales quiero llenar la tabla, así al momento de actualizar o eliminar un registro sea por medio de la llave que genero firebase, pero al intentar llenar la tabla con ese objeto recibido por firebase

me sale el siguiente mensaje:

"Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "items". Expected Array, got Object"

Por lo tanto únicamente me sirve cuando lleno la tabla mediante un arreglo de objetos, pero para ese caso no se como actualizar o eliminar en firebase ya que no tengo ningún id o key del objeto.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: podrias mostrar una imagen detallada de como se ve la coleccion comunicados en firebase?